# Image in a cell with a hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-cell-format

I need a cell that contains an image to also contain a hyperlink.

Following formula is the only one I found but doesn't work (error analyzing formula)

```
=HYPERLINK("URL", image("URL"))
```

Following formula I tried shows a blank cell but the link works

```
=hyperlink("URL"; Image("URL"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=HYPERLINK("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/";
     IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ2AY.png"; 3))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iZQgB5D8lEUUWkJM7bUn7CgmSDRv5ttb6G0gF43sBzQ/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: I found out that the problem was only with the image link. It was from Google Drive and the share link wasn't usable for this. So as you commented, this formula works just fine. Thank you

Comment: Hi i tried the demo but the hyperlink doesn't work . Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Your first formula worked for me. Perhaps there's something off about the way you've formatted one of the URL's?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am from EU and from what I have seen there are some slight differences between EU and other syntaxes, maybe that might be the reason?

Comment: yep, you are right. It was actually the difference between EU syntax and the rest of the world. We use a semicolon instead of a comma and it was the image link that wasn't working for this use